# BigInt from Javascript in C# equivalent

Tags: javascript, c#

I have written a script in Javascript, which converts a string to BigInt:

`BigInt("0x40000000061c924300441104148028c80861190a0ca4088c144020c60c831088")`

The result is: **28948022309972676171332135370609260321582865398090858033119816311589805691016**

I need to find a C# equivalent to this function. I've tried:

`Convert.ToInt64("0x40000000061c924300441104148028c80861190a0ca4088c144020c60c831088")` and `BigInteger.Parse("0x40000000061c924300441104148028c80861190a0ca4088c144020c60c831088",NumberStyles.Any)`

But both throw the exception: the value could not be parsed.

Does anyone have an idea, what function would work to get the result from the string, like BigInt() in JS?

Comment: Well `Int64` wouldn't do you any good anyway, as that value cannot fit in 64 bits.

Comment: Read the docs for `BigInteger.Parse`. You can in fact pass a hex value, but you have to give the method the "AllowHexSpecifier" style option, and you'll have to strip out the leading "0x" in your string source.

Comment: @Pointy is right. [Here is a Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/COcPsh) as an example.

Comment: [`BigInt.Parse` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Numerics_BigInteger_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_)

Comment: @Pointy Your solution worked, can you tell me what the leading 0x is ment for? Anyways thank you very much

Comment: @Sven2011 in many C-like programming languages, a leading "0x" indicates that the number is expressed in hexadecimal. For whatever reason, that C# method does not like that.

Answer (score 2):

> It should be converted BACK to a string format using the ToString()
> Method and you need to pass the parameter in ToString of "R" which
> tells it to output the BigInteger as itself.

This is from the documentation:

"In most cases, the ToString method supports 50 decimal digits of precision. That is, if the BigInteger value has more than 50 digits, only the 50 most significant digits are preserved in the output string; all other digits are replaced with zeros. However, BigInteger supports the "R" standard format specifier, which is intended to round-trip numeric values. The string returned by the ToString(String) method with the "R" format string preserves the whole BigInteger value and can then be parsed with the Parse or TryParse method to restore its original value without any loss of data."

You may want to try "R" instead of "N".

See this for more information and an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268260.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the leading "0x" to parse hex.

```
         private static BigInteger? ParseBigInteger(string input) {
            if (input.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                if (BigInteger.TryParse(input.Substring(2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var bigInt)) {
                    return bigInt;
                }
            }
            else if (BigInteger.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var bigInt)) {
                return bigInt;
            }
            return null;
        }
    

        //invocation
        var bigInt = ParseBigInteger("0x40000000061c924300441104148028c80861190a0ca4088c144020c60c831088");
// => result: 28948022309972676171332135370609260321582865398090858033119816311589805691016
```

Answer (score 0):

It corresponds to the long (or Int64), a 64-bit integer

For ref: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-a-bigint-in-javascript

Comment: The value in the OP will not fit in a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove 'x' character from the string and allow hex specifier then it will work:

BigInteger.Parse("0x40000000061c924300441104148028c80861190a0ca4088c144020c60c831088".Replace("x", string.Empty), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);